# New Node Express project, cannot get any app.get to be called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just started a new project and my app.get is never being called.  The site just loads forever without ever displaying anything.  I basically copy/pasted from another working project, but something isn't working here and I can't figure out what it is.  The code:

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("cookie-session");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const compression = require("compression");

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("connectString", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure && req.get('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
      return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
    }
    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
app.use(compression);
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    cookie: {secure: false},
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

require("./routes")(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{});
```

routes.js

```
const home = require("./controllers/home");

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("/", home.landingPage);
}
```

home.js

```
module.exports = {
    landingPage: function(req, res){
        console.log("landing");
        return res.render("/home.ejs");
    }
}
```

I've been staring at this for like an hour trying to figure out what is wrong, but I am at a loss.  The console.log("landing") is never run as well, so the whole landingPage function isn't called.  Can anybody help me out here?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you've set up the `compression` middleware. It needs to be done as

```
app.use(compression());
```

instead of

```
app.use(compression);
```

`compression` on its own does not yield a express middleware function, thus `next()` is never called and the request hangs forever.

See the official docs for [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression#expressconnect) details.